# Angular ngx-dropzone customize css

Tags: css, angular

I am a backend developer and bad at solving css problems. I need to change border of a ngx-dropzone button. I have written a css code block to fix this, but the border does not change.

How can I fix this?

```
dropzone>.dropzone.dz-wrapper .dz-message {
background-color: #eee;
border: none !important;  /* I would like to change here.*/
display: inline-block;
margin: 8px;
max-height: 100%;
max-width: calc(100% - 16px);
min-height: 40px;
min-width: calc(100% - 16px);
overflow: auto;
position: relative;
width: calc(100% - 16px); }
```

[image]

Comment: Kinda looks like your change hasn't been served correctly. Are you sure the project was rebuilt and the page was refreshed after you made your change?

Comment: I am sure that the page was refreshed after I made the change, and also the project was rebuilt. @SimonK

Comment: To clarify, did you add that entire css code block to try and modify just the border or did you edit the existing css and just change the one line? Your description suggests the former.

Comment: I have found the existing css code block on Chrome, and have copied it, and then I have pasted the code block to a css file that is called timeline-create-post.component.css. Finally, I have changed just one line that is about border of the ngx-dropzone button. In addition, I have changed random css classes for experimental purpose, it works, but I can not customize ngx-dropzone css styles. @SimonK

Comment: If you would like to examine the css file, here is my implementations. https://github.com/dogaanismail/DevPlatform/blob/master/DevPlatform.Api/DevPlatformSpa/src/app/components/timeline/timeline-create-post/timeline-create-post.component.css @SimonK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is `ViewEncapsulation`.
Angular encapsulates your styles to stop them from bleeding into other areas, as a result when you are attempting to style element that are generated outside of the component (i.e. the contents of `<dropzone>`) then you need to break the encapsulation.

```
dropzone ::ng-deep .dropzone.dz-wrapper .dz-message {
    border: none !important;
}
```

Also note that you only need to include the style you actually want to override. Anything you don't override will remain unchanged.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am a beginner for Angular. Your answer is very valuable to learn new beneficial informations.